# How to filter HTML nodes which have text in it from a html page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am new to web scraping and got an issue

I am using BeautifulSoup for scraping a webpage. I want to get nodes which have text in it.

I tried that using get_text() method like this

```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(open('FAQ3.html'), "html.parser")                               
  body = soup.find('body')                                                                                                                  
  for i in body:                                                                       
    if type(i) != bs4.element.Comment and type(i)!= bs4.element.NavigableString :     
      if i.get_text():                                                             
        print(i)
```

but get_text is giving node even if its child have text in it,

sample html:

```
<div>
  <div id="header">
        <script src="./FAQ3_files/header-home.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>
      this node contain text
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

while checking topmost div itself, it is returning the whole node as the innermost had text in it,

how to iterate over all nodes and filter only the nodes which actually have text in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used depth-first search for this, it solved my use case

```
def get_text_bs4(self, soup, leaf):
        if soup.name is not None:
            if soup.string != None and soup.name != 'script': 
                    if soup.text not in leaf:
                        leaf[soup.text] = soup
            for child in soup.children:
                self.get_text_bs4(child, leaf)
        return leaf
```